# How to terminate a php progress?

Tags: php

I use XAMPP to create my local server, and I have a PHP script, which contains a infinite loop for monitoring modification to the Database. I run this script in the web browser, and everything works fine, but I just cannot find a way to terminate it, even if I close the browser.

The only way is to stop the php progress is to shut down XAMPP server. But I want a more convenient way, because restarting the server is time consuming.

I am using OS X, and Safari.

Comment: use kill via command line

Comment: Really, you are using an infinite loop and it does not stop. This is totally expected. Just don't use an infinite loop in a script called from a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

exit — Output a message and terminate the current script

```
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop in a script that is accessed via browser is really bad. Because most browsers have a timeout. You should make a php script that is only called once and return a status (about your database modification). And on client side (in the browser) you should call that script via ajax and show the results in a div for example.

1. http://localhost/stat.php (echo's out some infos)
2. http://localhost/stat.html (contains your ajax call to stat.php)

Comment: Thanks, I found out that to run the php file in terminal is a better way to avoid this problem, which just need to press ctrl + c then the progress will be terminated.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I thought you must have access via browser ;)